# How to remove elements except any specific id

Tags: javascript, jquery

let say there is a parent id which contains many elements and i want to remove all elements except one.

***ex. :***

```
<div id = "parent_id">
  <div id = "id_1">
      <div id = "id_11"> </div>
      <div id = "id_11"> </div>
  </div>
  <div id = "id_2"> </div> 

  <div id = "id_n"> </div>   // No need to remove this id_n only
</div>
```

As i can remove innerHTML like this `document.getElementId('parent_id').innerHTML = '';`   but i need not to remove `id_n`. is there any way to do that using javascript or jQuery.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$("#parent_id").children(":not(#id_n)").remove();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#parent_id > :not(#id_n)").remove();
```

Answer (score 3):

No jQuery required:

```
const parent = document.querySelector('#parent_id');
const keepElem = document.querySelector('#id_n');
                
[...parent.children]
  .forEach(child => child !== keepElem ? parent.removeChild(child) : null);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the [Attribute Not Equals](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/) selector makes sense here.

```
$("#parent_id div[id!='id_n']").remove();
```

[Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/VjxNg/)

Answer (score 2):

For fun, POJS is a tad more code, but no jQuery :-)

```
var p = document.getElementById('parent_id');
var d = document.getElementById('id_n');
p.innerHTML = '';
p.appendChild(d);
```

A lot [faster too](http://jsperf.com/div-idn). ;-)

Comment: I added another test case, with another way of selecting in jQuery. The new test case is a lot faster than the old jQuery test case, although still slower than POJS.

Comment: yes, it can be deleted that way but also the object would be deleted of concern ID.

Comment: @user744587 - the element with id 'id_n' isn't deleted. A reference to it is stored, all content of the parent is removed from the DOM when its innerHTML is set to '', then the div is put back. It's just another approach to achieving the same result.

Comment: If the element that you're saying is an iframe this will cause a refresh. In my case that makes it unusable as an approach.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting all children other than id_n with jQuery:

```
$('#parent_id div').not('#id_n').remove();
```

If you'are going to delete the parent_id as well:

```
$('#id_n').insertAfter('#parent_id');
$('#parent_id').remove();
```

Comment: BTW, with modern jQuery `.not` method is recommended over `:not` pseudo-selector