# JS Remove all elements except a specific ID and its children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Responses to this:
[How to remove elements except any specific id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186280/how-to-remove-elements-except-any-specific-id)
are close to what I want but not quite.

In my case I am asking how I can remove all elements under parent id except id_n and its children: test1 and test2.  The elements need to be removed, not just hidden.

```
<div id = "parent_id">
  <div id = "id_1">
      <div id = "id_11"> test</div>
      <div id = "id_12">test </div>
  </div>
  <div id = "id_2"> test</div> 

  <div id = "id_n">id_n<br>
      <div id='test1'>test1<br><div>
      <div id='test2'>test2<br><div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

The result should be:

```
<div id = "parent_id">
  <div id = "id_n">id_n<br>
      <div id='test1'>test1<br><div>
      <div id='test2'>test2<br><div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Thanks for looking at this. Your suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: `$('#parent_id').children().not('#id_n').remove()`

Comment: Are you wanting this in vanilla JS, or are you also using jQuery?

Comment: He tagged jquery so it is assumed that jquery is acceptable

Comment: ```document.querySelectorAll('*:not(#id)').forEach(el => el.remove())```

Comment: @reski *document* is overly broad for this use case.  "parent_id" !== #id as well

Comment: @reski That will remove `id_11` and `id_12` even if you told it not to remove `id_1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery's `siblings` you remove all of it's children:

```
  $('#id_n').siblings().remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay after thinking about this, there is another approach using Array manipulation:

```
var parentElement = document.getElementById('#parent_id');
parentElement.innerHtml = [].splice.call(parentElement.children).filter(item, function() { 
  return item.id === childId; 
}).reduce((collatedHtml, item, function() { 
  return collatedHtml + item.innerHtml;
});
```

This grabs all the direct children of the parentElement and returns a new array (using [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)) before using [Array.Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to collate the innerHtml of all the children.

**Note:** the reason i'm not using the `...` prefix to convert to an Array is because it is not supported in IE 11 and below

Comment: This will not work. `remove` is not a prototypical method on arrays, and even if it was it wouldn't remove elements from the DOM. Reski's updated comment is closer to working, but this will not

Comment: @KevBot you are 100% correct! I will update the answer

Comment: this is entirely vanilla so no need for blasted jQuery